# How do you gauge the effect an index with have on a table write?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

After writing a query, I asked SSMS to display the execution plan and it told me that adding an index would speed up my query by over 99% - a pretty good deal - however, how can I gauge what the impact will be on writes; inserts, updates and deletions. That would seem to be a crucial piece of information and I doubt it is captured in the at 99+% improvement.

Comment: The "improvement" you see is specifically for the query you ran, and it should be taken with a pitch salt. The best thing to do is, honestly, test in your development environment first, and go from there.

Comment: Taking an insert as an example, when you insert a row, you also insert a row into the primary index and each of the other indexes defined for the table.  So, an insert on a table with a primary index and 9 other indexes could take up to 10 times as long.  In practice, most tables don't have 10 indexes and the database engine may be able to insert to indexes somewhat quicker.  As @Larnu said, test in your development environment.

Comment: To answer your actual question, you have to count the number of CUD transactions and compare it with the number of R transactions, taking into account that CUD transactions usually impact one row while R transactions read multiple rows.

Comment: Bear in mind that not having an index could also have an impact to updates, but as @Larnu has said you need to test for your mix of transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you would like help on **how to measure the impact** of extra indexes on deletes, inserts and updates (DUI).

This approach below gives an overview and an example. However, execution plan analysis can get quite involved and it often takes a bit of practice to understand them well (including warning signs for bad things).

This example tries to keep it simple. I'm inserting into a table (with and without indexes) and comparing the happens to performance.

Note I have a fairly fast disk (PCIE 4 SSD) and a heap of spare RAM on this machine, so things need to be reviewed in your own environment.

As background knowledge - you need to understand these

- Assuming it's not a heap, you have a clustered index on your table - this is effectively your whole table, sorted according to the clustered index.
- Other indexes (non-clustered indexes) are effectively a copy of selected fields from your table, sorted by the selected indexed fields.

To learn more about these, I strongly recommend and frequently point to Brent Ozar's [How to think like an SQL Server engine](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDYqU5RH_aX1VSVvjdla9TOKf939UhIDB) - which I found really improved my understanding dramatically. It also displays some of the things talked about here (e.g., reading execution plans) which could help.

As further background, there are two broad types of costs in deletes, inserts and updates (DUI).

- The processing required to determine where the data fits in the index (as they need to be sorted) - this is processor time (and it can also 'spill to disk' to reduce memory requirements but slow down the processing)
- The I/O required to actually insert into or update the index - this is the time for writing to transaction logs/etc.

To measure those costs involved, it is useful to

- Ensure you are using a recent version of SQL Server Management Studio

  - In recent versions, the main execution plan also includes the time taken to get to that point in the sub-branch (e.g., see image in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/thread-and-task-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#scheduling-parallel-tasks) ) which I use here. It also includes actual vs estimates, which help to identify where problems are occurring.
- Ensure, when you run your commands, you have 'Include *Actual* Execution Plan' turned on (not the 'estimated' plans)
- Before you start testing, run `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;` in your SSMS window. This uses the 'Messages' tab to show the amount of reads/etc, as well as time taken, for each command

Big provisos

- The time taken (and even reads) are not 100% stable, so take them as broad indicators of performance
- The cost % values shown for each step in the execution plans *are estimates from before it ran*, not the actual % in cost - you need to take these with a grain of salt

Now, one last thing before testing: Just writing data tends to have a linear relationship between the amount of data, and time taken e.g., writing 100MB of data will taken about 10x as long as 10MB.

However, sorting data is... extralinear (? I believe that's the word). It takes increasingly more work the more you have. Imagine sorting several items yourself. Sorting 1 data point is trivial; sorting 2-3 data points is very easy; sorting 10 becomes a bit more complex and is a lot more work than 2-3. Or to put it another way, sorting 100 rows of data is *more* than 10x the work as sorting 10 rows of data.

### Testing inserts

I have a table used for other purposes - it has an auto-incrementing primary key (also clustered index) called ID, and 4 columns for which I have UUIDs. Note there are no other indexes (yet).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col3] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col4] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col5] [varchar](100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
    )
```

It currently has a bit over a million rows, looking like this. For our purposes, random data.

```
ID  col2                                    col3                                    col4                                    col5
1   21997647-72C3-4C4D-A024-D6DBF772A488    EC92EBDF-B498-4075-B970-16D0D0175AFB    83A19064-80AF-40FE-9FC1-B501D9785764    342721C0-FC89-40F4-993F-BCFFC921A8FB
2   6450E2C6-A60D-4DF8-B961-FFA23AAD5A6F    70188DC9-A44A-4EE9-8266-B49F836EBC20    2D10DFD0-4D84-478A-BF4D-963C595173F6    7AE3A6FB-3F7A-471B-8B88-D68DB67B8124
```

I ran some tests to see how long various inserts took. I used the following type of command to insert 10^X values

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT NewID(), NewID(), NewID(), NewID()
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) A(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) B(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) C(n)
```

**Results (#reads, time taken) for initial version of table**

- Note that these are a summary from looking at the stats in Messages tab, as well as the execution plan

```
Inserting 1 row: 3 page reads, 0.000s 
Inserting 10 rows: 30 page reads, 0.000s 
Inserting 100 rows: 355 page reads, 0.000s 
Inserting 1000 rows: 3323 page reads, 0.003s 
Inserting 10,000 rows: 3083 page reads, 0.021s 
Inserting 100,000 rows: 29,458 page reads, 0.224s
```

These all have the same basic execution plan: create the relevant number of rows, then insert into the clustered index.

Note that they all seem to be linearly increasing - each one is about 10x as much as the previous (except for reads at 10,000 rows for some reason - I suspect it takes a different approach at that point).

---

For the next test (and for demonstration purposes) I then changed one thing: removed the PK/clustered index from the ID field, to col2 (full of UUIDs) and re-ran the testing.

**Results (#reads, time taken) with PK on col2**

```
Inserting 1 row: 15 page reads, 0.000s, same execution plan as above
Inserting 10 rows: 150 page reads, 0.000s
Inserting 100 rows: 1468 page reads, 0.002s
Inserting 1000 rows: 9194 page reads, 0.021s
Inserting 10,000 rows: 102,124 page reads, 0.192s
Inserting 100,000 rows: 570,604 page reads, 0.989s with a sort spilling to disk
```

This starts off as being about 10x as long, before imploding and spilling to disk at large numbers (somewhere between 10,000 rows and 100,000 rows at a time).

So, why did just changing the Primary Key (and clustered index) make everything go worse?

- In the first version of the table, when inserting the data, the rows just took the next IDs available (e.g., the IDENTITY column) so it did not need to sort them.
- Here, it needed to sort all the new rows (on Col2) to determine where in the clustered index to put them. This puts a hit on both processing and page reads.

---

Now, onto the effect of other non-clustered indexes. I returned the PK to the ID column, and added 4 indexes (one on each of the UUID columns).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_test_Col2] ON [test] (col2);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_test_Col3] ON [test] (col3);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_test_Col4] ON [test] (col4);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_test_Col5] ON [test] (col5);
```

... and then ran the process again

**Results (#reads, time taken) with Non-clustered indexes on 4 UUID columns**

```
Inserting 1 row: 55 page reads, 0.000s, same execution plan as original
Inserting 10 rows: 519 page reads, 0.002s
Inserting 100 rows: 4460 page reads, 0.018s
Inserting 1000 rows: 38,832 + 2197 page reads, 0.153s, execution plan now has separate branches for sorting for nonclustered indexes
Inserting 10,000 rows: 253,852 + 21,961 page reads, 0.614s 
Inserting 100,000 rows: 1,623,969 + 297,694 page reads, 2.861s, and in execution plan, the sorting spills to disk
```

Here, when inserting rows,

- Even though I added only 4 indexes, the cost is about 10x worse (and growing) because the initial insert didn't need to sort, while the other indexes do
- The cost grows faster than linear, so the more rows, the worse it gets
- There's a tipping point somewhere between 100 and 1000 rows at a time. Before that, it follows the same basic approach as last time, but it does need to write to more locations and do more sorting.
- If you look at it, it is still amazingly fast. For 10 rows, it inserts them, sorts them, also writes the index updates, all in 1/500th of a second. And it does the same for 10,000 rows in about half a second.

If I were running this command, say, a few times a minute, I probably wouldn't worry if i was doing up to a hundred rows or so each time. If you only ever insert/update a handful or rows at a time, then you're probably OK to use whatever indexes you want (as the sorts are easy/cheap and there's not much to write).

However, note that you will need to do this testing on your own machine, with your own commands. Inserting and sorting large nvarchars, for example, may be a lot more work than inserting and sorting ints.

And as was said above in the comments on the question by @Gilbert, indexes can speed up updates and deletes.

For example, if you *didn't* have an index on col2, and you ran the command

```
DELETE FROM dbo.test
WHERE col2 = '21997647-72C3-4C4D-A024-D6DBF772A488'
```

It would need to read the *entire table* to find the relevant rows.

However, if Col2 was indexed, then it's already sorted so it can go straight to the relevant spot and delete the row. Yes, it will also need to update the other indexes (so there is more to write). But in this case, that would be a lot faster than reading all the million+ rows.